# Use multiple css stylesheets in the same html page

Tags: html, css

How would I use multiple CSS stylesheets in the same HTML page where both stylesheets have a banner class, for instance. How do you specify which class you are referring to?

Answer (score 26):

Style sheets are, effectively, concatenated into a single style sheet in the order in which they appear in the HTML source.

The [normal rules for applying rulesets](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) then apply (i.e. by [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) with the last ruleset that defines a given property winning in the event of a tie and [!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#important-rules) throwing a spanner into the works)

Answer (score 20):

Yes, you can include multiple style sheets, but you need to label them as alternate style sheets and give the user some way to activate them using JavaScript - perhaps by clicking a link.

To create an alternate style sheet:

```
<link type="text/css" href="nameOfAlterateStyleSheet.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="Blue" />
```

Next create a method in your Javascript file that will: 1. Load all the style sheets in an array 2. Example:

```
function getCSSArray()
{
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
var link;
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
    link = links[i];
    if(/stylesheet/.test(link.rel))
    {
        sheets.push(link);
    }
}

    return sheets;
}
```

Then go through the array using some type of if/else loop that disables the style sheets you don't want and enables the style sheet you want. (You can write a separate method or insert the loop into the method above. I like to use the onload command to load the CSS array with the page, then call the printView method.)

```
function printView()
{
var sheet;
var title1 = "printVersion";
for(i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++)
{
    sheet = sheets[i];
            if(sheet.title == title1)
    {
        sheet.disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        sheet.disabled = true;
    }
```

Lastly, create code in your HTML document that the user will activate the JavaScript method such as:

```
 <a href="#" onClick ="methodName();">Link Name</a>
```

Comment: A few things worth noting about both the question and this answer. **This answer is correct, but only if you want multiple different styles**.
You can have multiple sheets defined the same way as primary one. As long as they don't alter the same attributes - you're fine. If 2 stylesheets contradict eachother, then you should get the style of the one that is processed last (Quentin has written a concise answer).

Answer (score 6):

You can't control which you're referencing, given the same level of [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) in the rule (e.g. both are simply `.banner`) the stylesheet included last will win.

It's per-property, so if there's a combination going on (for example one has `background`, the other has `color`) then you'll get the combination...if a property is defined in both, whatever it is the last time it appears in stylesheet order wins.

Answer (score 3):

You can't and don't.

All CSS rules on page will be applied (the HTML "knows" nothing about this process), and the individual rules with the highest specificity will "stick". Specificity is determined by the selector and by the order they appear in the document. All in all the point is that this is part of the *cascading*. You should refer to one of the very many CSS tutorials on the net.

Answer (score 1):

You never refer to a specific style sheet. All CSS rules in a document are internally fused into one.

In the case of rules in both style sheets that apply to the same element with the same specificity, the style sheet embedded later will override the earlier one.

You can use an element inspector like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see which rules apply, and which ones are overridden by others.

Answer (score 1):

The one you include last will be the one that is used. Note however that if any rules has !important in the first stylesheet they will take priority.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as your stylesheet(s) referring to ("selecting") elements in your HTML page, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple alternative:

1/ Suppose we have two css files, say my1.css and my2.css. In the html document head type a link to one of them, within an element with an ID, say "demo":

2/ In the html document head body define two buttons calling two JS functions:

select css1 
 select css2

3/ Finally, in the JS file type the two functions as follows:

function select_css1() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '';
}

function select_css2() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '';
}

Answer (score -1):

you can include more styles.

```
<link rel="preload stylesheet" href="style1.css" as="style">
<link rel="preload stylesheet" href="style2.css" as="style">
<link rel="preload stylesheet" href="Folder/Subfolder/style3.css" as="style">
```

Maybe it's not a 'best-practice'... but it has potential: you may have a 'palette.css' where u keep color-classes only that are 'shared'... or to think in a more 'componentistic way'

Rawly you can do similar with 'mediaquery' to support different resolutions
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question, specifically the last half: "where both stylesheets have a banner class, for instance. How do you specify which class you are referring to?"

Answer (score -5):

You can't. The last stylesheet  you specify will be the one html page will use. Think of it as a big single .css document.

Comment: Fail.  You can definitely include multiple CSS files.