# I want to use multiple CSS files

Tags: html, css

I have 2 css files:

```
 <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="css/day/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

main.css

```
#MainHeader
        {
            position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0;
            width:100%;
            height:300px;

        }

        #ContentContainor
        {
            width: 80%;
            position:absolute;
            top: 350px;
            left: 10%;
        }
```

style.css

```
#MainHeader
{
    background:green;   
}
#ContentContainor
{
    background: yellow;
}
```

I want one to position the site: main.css and the other is a user chosen style style.css.
The main.css works correctly but the style.css dosn't seem to be working.

I'll be honest I don't know if this is even possible; I'm experimenting.

If some one has a solution please comment.

Comment: How do you call the style.css ? Maybe your scripting language has an error. And yes, it is totally possible.

Comment: That should work, check your css paths

Comment: ***dosn't seem to be working*** how doesn't it work?

Comment: the <link >, its at the top of the question

Comment: the background dosn't go the colour I have set

Comment: What you did should work. Try loading the linked CSS files in your browser, and make sure that their URL matches the relative path you wrote in your `href`. Note that the path you wrote is relative to the page’s URL because it doesn’t start with `/`. Also double-check that the styles in both files are ones that would have an effect on the page so you would notice if they actually worked.

Comment: yes, it should take the styles from both files if you have positioned them in the correct folders. Try using firebug to check if the styles are loaded.

Comment: This post could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284499/use-multiple-css-stylesheets-in-the-same-html-page.

Comment: that seemed to work, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you're stating is absolutely possible.

Let's say you have two stylesheets, as you mentioned:

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/day/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The main.css will hold your structural (position, dimensions, etc) CSS, and the day/style.css will hold your design (color, animations, etc) CSS.

If your `css/main.css` has the following CSS:

```
#main_header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}

#content_container{
    width: 80%;
    position:absolute; 
    top: 350px;
    left: 10%;
}
```

you can append styles (in `css/day/style.css`) as follows:

```
#main_header {
    background-color: #00F;
}

#content_container{
    color: #F00;
    background-color: #0F0;
}
```

you can also override and 'lock' styles (in `css/day/style.css`) as follows:

```
#main_header {
    height: 200px; /* override */
}

#content_container{
    position: relative !important; /* override and 'lock' */
}
```

As a last note, you want to make sure your CSS files are being loaded and that your HTML is correctly formatted. Use your browsers Developer Tool / Firebug to make sure that the CSS is being loaded. For example, in Chrome, clicking on the Developer Tool (F12) tab called Network and reloading the page will tell you whether files are being loaded ok (200/304) or whether there are issues (ie, 404, 403, 500, etc)