# Use local css file if link to online css file is dead

Tags: javascript, html, css

---

**The problem:**

---

I am using [w3.css](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_downloads.asp)(if you enter now `w3schools.com` site is down for maintenance) for styling my website.The problem here is that `w3schools.com` is going down from times to times.

Then my website looks creepy and i don't need that.

So i have a local copy of the `w3.css` on the computer and up to the server which is holding the website.

Online:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
```

Local:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/w3.css">
```

---

**The question:**

---

How i know when the link which i am pointing on `w3schools` is dead,so i can use the local `w3.css` file.How i can do that?

**1**)Detect if broken

**2**)Use the local css before the website has been loaded

---

**Finally**

---

What big companies are doing for that?If `3-4` WebServices go down the whole company is going down.....

I am new to web developing so..Thank you...

---

**Edit:(I have something in mind)**

Loading the `local(...site in on a server,that local i mean)` and the `w3schools` file , but that will increase the site loading...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/18748763/6746555

Comment: @Mahi  Can you provide an example?I will find it very useful.Like how i will change `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">` to work ?What i will add to `stylesheet`?Thanks..

Comment: Why don't you always use the local copy?

Comment: I think using it from W3Schools.com will be better cause i have a chance that the file is downloaded from another user somewhere near...The server i use is for example Canada, and W3Schools has many servers here and there.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible with PHP. I haven't tested it but it should work.

Put this inside your `<head>` tag.

```
<?php

if (isDomainAvailible('http://www.w3schools.com')){
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">';
} else {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/w3.css">';
}

//returns true, if domain is availible, false if not
   function isDomainAvailible($domain)
   {
           //check, if a valid url is provided
           if(!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
           {
                   return false;
           }

           //initialize curl
           $curlInit = curl_init($domain);
           curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
           curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
           curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
           curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

           //get answer
           $response = curl_exec($curlInit);

           curl_close($curlInit);

           if ($response) return true;

           return false;
   }

?>
```

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/check-if-website-is-available/

Comment: I have to add it on every html page i have,right?Or i can add it on a php file and call it?If so let me know... :)

Comment: `isDomainAvailible` what's this? Where is it defined?

Comment: @GoXR3Plus Yes.

Comment: keep in mind that you have a typo in `isDomainAvailible()`

Answer (score 1):

for check if w3.css is working you can use something like this. instead of src put w3.css image of logo or something .

```js
function checkImage (src, up, down) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = up; 
    img.onerror = down;
    img. src = src;
}

checkImage( "https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", function(){ alert("up"); }, function(){ alert("down"); } );
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question nor does it explain anything. It may very well be that the logo of w3 is accessible yet the stylesheet is not.

Comment: @mmenschig so OP can put the if else condition and in if condition use w3 stylesheet and in else condition use custom stylesheet

Comment: so why don't you edit your post so it does what you're saying.

Comment: @mmenschig Op asked two different question . i answered for 1st .

Answer (score 0):

Why not use JS like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.each(document.styleSheets, function(i,sheet){
  if(sheet.href=='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css') {
    var rules = sheet.rules ? sheet.rules : sheet.cssRules;
    if (rules.length == 0) {
      $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/local/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css" />').appendTo('head');
    }
 }
})
</script>
```

`$.each(document.styleSheets)` iterates through the styleSheets of the document. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets for more info.

Then we specifically check if `http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css` is accessible. We use the ternary operator `var rules = sheet.ruless ? sheet.rules : sheet.cssRules;` The ternary operator works similar to an if statement, rules becomes sheet.rules if sheet.rules evaluates to true. If it is false it will become sheet.cssRules.

Lastly we check if there's anything in `rules`. If there isn't, we fallback to our local stylesheet solution and add it to the `<head></head>` of the document.

Although you may run into issues when using a very slow to load CDN. Alternatively you could use the `onerror` event

Comment: Thanks for recommendation.Shouldn't it be into a method so i can call it from every html page?

Comment: Thanks! i got it,i need you provide the best solution you have in mind, i mean if it was your website which it has 5 html pages(simple enough) how do you call this method? you add these lines into every `html` page or you wrap it into a method save it into an `.js` file and call it from the `<head>` using the name of the method.I really need to know it. :)

Comment: I need it to be more general, accepting two variables`function checkStatus(online, local) {..}`,online and local url,and then check if online is available , if not use the local.Yours is working well but imagine that i have and another css files like this.Providing it i will accept the answer :)

Comment: Ok, this is actually easy to do. I will edit my answer shortly.

Comment: The W3Schools is online now  , i tried your solution modifying everywhere `w3.css` with `w2.css` to check if it works,but it doesn't :( . Entering the first `if(sheet.href=='....'` but then nothing...I added to alerts one after the first if and one after the second if  `if (rules.length == 0)`.The first alert works the second not... Seems that it doesn't pass from the `ternary expression` `var rules = sheet.rules ? sheet.rules : sheet.cssRules;`