# anyway to check that a img tag is broken or 404'd; without add'l network request

Tags: javascript

I am using CasperJS to scrape some items, so I can't get on the page early enough to add load and error events on img tags. I would also prefer to not have to do a new XHR request for each image to determine it's validity.

Is there any way to select an image tag and determine if there is an image actually there or if it is not in which the alt text is displayed? JS only, after the page is fully loaded.

**This is NOT A DUPLICATE. I am specifically asking if there is a way to do this without another network request. Other questions only have answers that require creating a new image with a new source and thus another network request.**

/ Edit

Specifically looking for asserting if am image is loaded after it is complete (`document.querySelector('#myImage').complete // returns true`:

- No new network request (includes creating a new image with a new source)
- No onload/onerror events (requires doing so before page is loaded)
- Assert that `#myImage` is broken without the above

Comment: The `onerror` event fires if the image couldn't be loaded

Comment: Yes - I can't get on the page early enough to add that event though. I am wondering if there is a way to select an image with say `document.querySelector('img')` and assert if the image is loaded or not without events or again, new network requests. It seems insane that such an attribute or prop wouldn't exist..

Comment: you want this ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440377/use-local-css-file-if-link-to-online-css-file-is-dead/40440750#40440750

Comment: @Mahi no, creating a new image with a new source is another network request.

Comment: Then the answer is "no", there's no way to do what you want. If you can't add event handlers before the image loads, you have to load the images source once more.

Comment: @adeneo, came up with two methods that work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of working, I was able to find two methods that seem to work:

**HTML**

```
<img id="imageA" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
<img id="imageB" src="https://www.google.com/broken.png">
```

**Setup**

```
var imageA = document.querySelector('#imageA');
var imageB = document.querySelector('#imageB');

console.log(imageIsValid(imageA)); // returns true
console.log(imageIsValid(imageB)); // returns false
```

**JavaScript Method 1**

```
function imageIsValid(img) {
  return !!img.naturalHeight && !!img.naturalWidth;
}
```

The natural height and width of broken images will always be 0.

https://jsfiddle.net/2xLsenpp/

**JavaScript Method 2**

```
function imageIsValid(img) {
  if (img.complete) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    try {
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      return true;
    } catch(e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8gdp8nzw/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly you would use it , but here is the code snippet from w3schools.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onerror" event to an img element.</p>

    <img id="myImg" src="image.gif">

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("myImg").onerror = function() {myFunction()};

    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The image could not be loaded.";
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This would require getting a script on the page before the image loads. I am curious if there is any way to assert on images that are technically `complete` that if an image exists in the element.